# Concatenating two observables with an action in between

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I'm pretty new to rx so the questions keep popping up :)

I have two observable sequences, first I want to run one to completion, and then begin subscribing to the other (they're both cold). I believe Concat() will do this (please correct me if I'm wrong).

But what if I want to do "something" after the first has completed, before the other one starts - say for example log something to the console?

The very simple code I have is along the lines of this:

```
var subject = new ReplaySubject<IResponse>();
observable1
    .Concat(observable2)
    .Subscribe(
        subject.OnNext,
        () =>
        {
            subject.OnCompleted();
        });
```

Can I do that?

Comment: You probably want .Multicast(subject).Connect(); here instead of Subscribe

Comment: @Paul: Thanks for your comment. I looked up the methods you mention, but I'm not sure why it would be better here? Could you elaborate on that? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Do operator is perfect for logging and has the same method signatures as the Subscribe operator so you can perform actions OnNext, OnError and OnComplete.

```
  var observable1 = Observable.Range(0,10);
  var observable2 = Observable.Range(10, 10);

  observable1.Do(_ => { }, 
         () => Console.WriteLine("Log First Sequence Complete"))
     .Concat(observable2)
     .Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine("On Next Value {0}", i),
         () => Console.WriteLine("Log Both Sequences Complete"));
```

Comment: Yes! All tests pass now. Thanks! :)

Comment: Keep in mind though, that since your sources are *cold*, that means if you have two subscribers, you will end up executing the Do clause *twice*. If you don't want that to happen, you should use Publish() then call Connect()